# Number of regex matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the `finditer` function in the `re` module to match some things and everything is working.

Now I need to find out how many matches I've got. Is it possible without looping through the iterator twice? (one to find out the count and then the real iteration)

Some code:

```
imageMatches = re.finditer("<img src\=\"(?P<path>[-/\w\.]+)\"", response[2])
# <Here I need to get the number of matches>
for imageMatch in imageMatches:
    doStuff
```

Everything works, I just need to get the number of matches before the loop.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you know you will want all the matches, you could use the `re.findall` function. It will return a list of all the matches. Then you can just do `len(result)` for the number of matches.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: findall finds non-overlapping. From the documentation: Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler & JoshD: Thanks for the clarification, the parts will never overlap so that won't be a problem for me in this case. The only annoyance with re.findall is that i loose my named groups, but it works so it's good enough.

Comment: Okay, I posted my answer anyway. Happy trails.

Comment: `len(re.findall(pattern, string))`

Answer (score 15):

If you always need to know the length, and you just need the content of the match rather than the other info, you might as well use `re.findall`.  Otherwise, if you only need the length sometimes, you can use e.g.

```
matches = re.finditer(...)
...
matches = tuple(matches)
```

to store the iteration of the matches in a reusable tuple.  Then just do `len(matches)`.

Another option, if you just need to know the total count after doing whatever with the match objects, is to use

```
matches = enumerate(re.finditer(...))
```

which will return an `(index, match)` pair for each of the original matches.  So then you can just store the first element of each tuple in some variable.

But if you need the length first of all, and you need match objects as opposed to just the strings, you should just do

```
matches = tuple(re.finditer(...))
```

Answer (score 11):

```
#An example for counting matched groups
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+).(\d+).(\w+).(\w+)', re.IGNORECASE)
search_str = "My 11 Char String"

res = re.match(pattern, search_str)
print(len(res.groups())) # len = 4  
print (res.group(1) ) #My
print (res.group(2) ) #11
print (res.group(3) ) #Char
print (res.group(4) ) #String
```

Comment: I think `len(res.groups())` throw exception when re match nothing

Answer (score 7):

If you find you need to stick with `finditer()`, you can simply use a counter while you iterate through the iterator.

Example:

```
>>> from re import *
>>> pattern = compile(r'.ython')
>>> string = 'i like python jython and dython (whatever that is)'
>>> iterator = finditer(pattern, string)
>>> count = 0
>>> for match in iterator:
        count +=1
>>> count
3
```

If you need the features of `finditer()` (not matching to overlapping instances), use this method.

Comment: Yea I thought of doing that but due to things in my "doStuff" code won't work without adding a lot of extra code in various places. Thanks for the tip anyway :)

Comment: I would use `for count, match in enumerate(iterator):` in the case of Rafe's code.

Comment: @Tony: thanks, forgot about enumerate. If you do use enumerate, though, it will give you the highest *index*, not the actual number of matches; for that, you'd have to add 1.

Comment: `for count, match in enumerate(iterator)` regresses badly where there are no matches. Adding `count = -1` before the loop may be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little old, but this but here is a concise function for counting regex patterns.

```
def regex_cnt(string, pattern):
    return len(re.findall(pattern, string))

string = 'abc123'

regex_cnt(string, '[0-9]')
```

Answer (score 0):

For those moments when you really want to avoid building lists:

```py
import re
import operator
from functools import reduce
count = reduce(operator.add, (1 for _ in re.finditer(my_pattern, my_string)))
```

Sometimes you might need to operate on huge strings. This might help.

Comment: I'd suggest:
`sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(my_pattern, my_string))`
No need for the complexity of reduce and operation.add

Answer (score 0):

if you are using finditer method best way you can count the matches is to initialize a counter and increment it with each match

Comment: This solution is already proposed - and implemented - in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3895679/5320906) from 2010.