# Count the number of times that string appears (Python3)

Tags: string, python-3.x, count

I want to count the number of times that the string `code` appears anywhere in the given string, except for the letter `d`, so `cope` and `cooe count.

```
count_code('aaacodebbb') → 1
count_code('copexxcozecode') → 3
```

I tried to write it like this:

```
def count_code(str):
    return str.count("code")
```

However I cannot figure out to count `cope` or `coze` and so on as a `code`.
It would be really appreciated if it is explained in detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of regex matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895646/number-of-regex-matches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use regex. The script would look something like this.

```
import re

str = 'copexxcozecode'

matches = re.findall(r'(co[\S]e)', str)
print(matches) # ['cope', 'coze', 'code']
```

Here's a breakdown of the code:

`re.findall` returns all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. This means that it will be easy to count by just calling `len(matches)`.

`r'(co[\S]e)'` means that given string of `str` will match based on the patter of the letters `co` + one instance of a string character (technically a non whitespace character) + the letters `se`

Comment: Beat me to the draw!! This is the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answering in detail. This is very easy to understand !!