# Search string for variable substrings in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I'm looking for a function in Python that will be able to search strings for a degenerate substring. Basically:

```
    N = ("B","C","D")
    s = "DADBADCAD"
    m = "NAD"
    s.count(m)
      3
```

Basically if Python sees "NAD" in m, I want it to interpret it as "BAD", "CAD", and "DAD" and then find every iteration of those strings in s.

Comment: You can try using regex and then finding all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895646/number-of-regex-matches

Comment: Where does `N` get used at all in this code? Ignoring that capitalized variable names violates PEP 8.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: How is the count of M in S == 3? It doesnt contain the letter N

Comment: I made an edit to clarify, but I want Python to be able to recognize the variable N in the string m. I know that as written Python will not see N (the variable) in "NAD" the string, so I assume I need to change "NAD" to some other type of object, but I don't know what changes will actually be useful.